# How can a single file system object be both a symlink and a directory?

Tags: bash, symlink

When I  `ls`  it, it's a directory with a bunch of files in it.  But when I   `ls -l`  it, it's a symlink to something that's NOT a directory. What's going on — how is it possible?

```
$ ls /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver/module   

coresize  holders   initstate  refcnt    srcversion  uevent
drivers   initsize  notes      sections  taint  
$    
$  ls -l /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver/module  

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 13 05:24 /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver/module -> ../../../../module/cdc_ether   
$  
$ readlink  /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver/module  

../../../../module/cdc_ether  
$  
$  ls `readlink  /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver/module`  

ls: cannot access '../../../../module/cdc_ether': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please post the contents as text rather than a screenshot.

Comment: What's impossible about it? `ls` dereferences the symlink by default, and doesn't for `ls -l`.

Comment: @muru shouldn't deferencing show me "../../../../module/cdc_ether"  as the "readlink" command subsequently shows ?   
ls follows the link to a directory while readlink follows it to something else ?

Comment: `readlink` doesn't do any following (I think you need `-f` for that), it just printed the target of the link. The last `ls` just gets a relative path, and you're in the wrong directory for it.

Comment: Oh ok --- now I got it -- I was confused about a couple of things--       
1. I thought "cdc_ether" was a file. And /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver/module a symlink to it. Its not, its actually a directory.  
2. I didn't know that "../../../../module/cdc_ether"  is actually relative to the location of the symlink and not my present working directory. Which made it difficult to find "cdc_ether".  
Now everything solved. 
Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is relative, so you need to change to its parent directory for your last command to work:

```
cd /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver
ls `readlink module`
```

Alternatively, you can ask `readlink` to canonicalise the link:

```
ls `readlink -e /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver/module`
```

Comment: Oh ok --- now I got it -- I was confused about a couple of things -- (1)  I thought "cdc_ether" was a file. And /sys/class/net/enp0s20u1/device/driver/module a symlink to it. Its not, its actually a directory.     
(2). I didn't know that "../../../../module/cdc_ether" is actually relative to the location of the symlink and not my present working directory. Which made it difficult to find "cdc_ether". Now everything solved. Thanks for the comments :) –